# Using rails and ajax to dynamically render content.

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am really in a bind on how to get this last step of my app done.

I want to dynamically replace the main content without needing to refresh the page.

The application.html.erb looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <!-- ><div id="headcontainer">
            <header>
            </header>
        </div> -->
        <div id="maincontentcontainer">
            <div id="maincontent">
                <div class="section group">
                    <div class="col span_1_of_7">
                        <%= render :partial => "shared/menu" %>
                    </div>
                    <div id="replace">
                        <%= yield %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have my menu partial which when clicked I want to dynamically replace the content of the #replace div

```
<ul class='kwicks kwicks-vertical'>
    <li id='panel-1'><%= link_to_unless_current image_tag('keyIssues.png'), :remote => true %></li>
    <li id='panel-2'><%= link_to_unless_current image_tag('pollVsLeader.png'), :remote => true  %></li>
    <li id='panel-3'><%= link_to_unless_current image_tag('keyBubble.png'), :remote => true  %></li>
    <li id='panel-4'><%= link_to_unless_current image_tag('dataSource.png'),  :remote => true  %></li>
    <li id='panel-5'><%= link_to_unless_current image_tag('group14.png'), :remote => true  %></li>
</ul>
```

I had some Jquery that I was using to remove the div and replace it.. but it is replacing the div with the fill contents of the page.. a page within a page here is some of the code:

```
$(function(){
  $('#panel-1').click(function(){
    $("#remove").remove();
    $.get('../key_issues/index.html', function(html){
      $('.col.span_6_of_7').remove();
      $('.section.group').append(html);  
    });
  });
});
```

I have tried the ajax-rails gem but i cant get that to work either.. can someone offer some advice please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple way

```
<li id='panel-1'><%= link_to image_tag('keyIssues.png'), some_path_to_url_controller , :remote => true %></li>
```

**Controller code**

```
def some_method
 //your code
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js
 end
end
```

**some_method.js.erb**

```
$("#replace_div").html("<%= j render partial: 'your_partial' %>");
```

For more info [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Can you explain the controller code please..?

Comment: making your link to remote true, it will search for the response in js format. You do what ever you want to display in the replace div.

Comment: Specifically, link will submit an Ajax request to call a remote function in  controller, which subsequently queries some data and returns a JS object to the page. replace the content/ partial with the ajax.

Comment: Sorry if this seems like a dumb question,.. where is some_method called from (i cant see it anywhere) ?  Does that go in application_controller.js?

Comment: the href in your link_to image_tag, is 'some_path_to_url_controller' where you basically put your path to app/controller method, adjust this with your own routes and methods. then click the link it definitely reach the controller/method.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense now.. but some more questions: in your example should some_method.js.erb be called format.js.erb ? I assume that the link_to runs the specified controller#method and then runs the js file that contains: $("#replace_div").html("<%= j render partial: 'your_partial' %>"); . Is that correct? Sorry for keep asking questions..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39992/discussion-between-nate-uni-and-debadatt)